# .NET List<T>.Sort uses introsort, why is the worst case O(n^2)?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, sorting

The .NET documentation of `List<T>.Sort` mentions the asymptotic runtime: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2

> On average, this method is an O(n log n) operation, where n is Count; in the worst case it is an O(n^2) operation.

It also mentions that it's implemented using `Array.Sort`, which also has a runtime claim at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2

> For arrays that are sorted by using the Heapsort and Quicksort algorithms, in the worst case, this method is an O(n log n) operation, where n is length.

It also mentions that introsort started being used with .NET 4.5, in 2012.

Why is `List<T>.Sort` still O(n^2) in the worst case? Or is that just a mistake in the documentation and it's in fact O(n log n)?

Comment: Well the documentation specifies that in some cases it uses a QuickSort algorithm, and QuickSort has, worst case, *O(n^2)* time complexity.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Introsort works by using Quicksort *except* in the cases where Quicksort would exhibit its O(n^2) behavior.

Comment: `List.Sort` delegates to `Array.Sort` (as in, calls it directly, not used as a subroutine in some more elaborate algorithm) and the docs in fact mention this explicitly, so these pages are in direct contradiction. I haven't checked the edit history to see which one's newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) is O(n log n) in the worst case.

As far as I know, the only reason introsort exists in the first place is to avoid the O(n<sup>2</sup>) worst-case running time of quicksort.

So the link saying it's O(n<sup>2</sup>) is wrong.

Note that the two links give exactly the same algorithm, word-for-word (minus what appears to be a typing error - Log<sup>N</sup> instead of log N).

> - If the partition size is fewer than 16 elements, it uses an insertion sort algorithm
> - If the number of partitions exceeds 2 log n, where n is the range of the input array, it uses a Heapsort algorithm.
> - Otherwise, it uses a Quicksort algorithm.

Yet they end by concluding different worst-case complexities.

> [in the worst case, this method is an O(n log n) operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2)

versus

> [in the worst case it is an O(n<sup>2</sup>) operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

I think it might be an approximation issue. Take your second quote:

> For arrays that are sorted by using the Heapsort and Quicksort algorithms, in the worst case, this method is an O(n log n) operation, where n is length.

I've seen tons of textbooks/articles describing quicksort as being O(n log n), while in fact you can double check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) and verify its worst case cost is actually O(n²). That's usually because in practice, quicksort is almost always faster than other sorting algorithms that on paper have a smaller worst case cost. For instance, you'll see that the block sort has O(n log n) as worst case, but still the quicksort will be faster in the majority of practical applications.

As for your first quote: I'd say that's because the docs mention the worst cose among the possible cases. Specifically:

- If the partition size is smaller than 16, it goes with insertion sort, which is O(n²) (though it can be seen as O(1) here as it's bounded to 16).
- If the partition […] it goes with heapsort, which is O(n log n).
- Otherwise it goes with quicksort, which is in fact O(n²).

So I'd say that could be why the `List<T>.Sort` method as being described as O(n log n) on average, and O(n²) in the worst case here.

Comment: If partition size is smaller than 16, then any sort you do is O(1), because the size is bounded. This has no relevance on asymptotic complexity.
Quicksort is indeed O(n^2), but the heapsort is supposed to be used to avoid the O(n^2) cases of quicksort. That's why the Array.Sort is O(n log n), even though it uses Quicksort in some cases.

Comment: @Winani  The best thing you can do is to inspect the source: [IntrospectiveSort](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/arraysorthelper.cs,293) (triggered if the assembly is at least targeting FW 4.5). You can see that the sort method is selected in a dynamic way, based first on the partition size. See what is used when `partitionSize` is `<= 16`, then *recalibrated*.

Comment: @Winani Yeah you're right, the first case was still O(1), my bad. As for the rest, you might indeed try to inspect the source, but I still think it might very well be a case of "imprecision"/approximation in the docs.

Comment: While it's standard to say quick-sort is O(n log n), I don't I've ever seen anyone say the **worst**-case is O(n log n) (which is what the quote in the question does). Also, this is a **hybrid** algorithm - only **part** of it is quicksort, and the algorithm exists specifically to avoid the worst-case complexity - your analysis seems to misunderstand how the algorithm actually works.

Comment: @Dukeling I didn't mean to do an analysis at all here, of course the quicksort is O(n²) in the worst case scenario, and of course the introsort is O(n log n). What I said is that I've seen that in non-specific textbooks (eg. an OOP textbook instead of a proper algorithm design one) the quicksort is sometimes described as just being O(n log n), under the assumption that it's "generally as fast as an O(n log n) algorithm". Of course this is technically wrong, I just thought maybe this is what had happened in that description as well.

Comment: It depends on point of view, both O(1) and O(n^2) are correct for insertion sort here. Mathematically, every array in .net is bounded to 4 billion elements, so every sorting algorithm is O(1), but it is not the only way to see things.